# counting number of zeros and ones in a byte

Tags: assembly, x86

I previously posted a program to find the total number of 1s in a byte. Now I am trying to find the number of 0s in a byte. Following is my code:

```
MOV AL,1
MOV CX,08H
MOV BX,0000H
MOV DX,0000H

Zero:


SHR AL,01H

JZ ero

JNZ ZrO

ero: INC BX

ZrO: INC DX


LOOP Zero

hlt
```

The program isn't giving the right answer. Any guesses where am I wrong?

Comment: If `ero:` is jumped to, it falls through to `Zr0`, so you would increase both `BX` and `DX` with the call making the result wrong. One possible solution is to jmp to `LOOP Zero` after the first `INC BX`.

Comment: `shr` sets the ZF if the entire operand becomes zero after the shift, not if the bit that was just shifted out was zero.

Answer (score 3):

The bit which is shifted-out from AL goes to the carry-flag, not to the zero-flag. Change your conditional jumps:

```
    MOV AL,1     ; An investigated byte.    
    MOV CX,08H   ; Number of bits in the byte. 
    MOV BX,0000H ; Result: number of 1s.
    MOV DX,0000H ; Result: number of 0s.
Zero:SHR AL,01H  ; Shift the byte, least significant bit to CF.
    JNC ZrO
ero:INC BX      ; Count 1s. 
    JMP Skip
ZrO:INC DX      ; Count 0s.
Skip:LOOP Zero   ; Repeat CX times.
    hlt
```

BTW there is a specialized instruction for this task on new Intel processors (NEHALEM):
https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/popcnt

```
    MOV AL,1     ; An investigated byte.  
    XOR AH,AH    
    POPCNT BX,AX ; Count the number of 1s in AX and put result to BX.
    MOV DX,8
    SUB DX,BX    ; The number of 0s in AL is 8-BX.
```

Comment: Isn't the total number of 0s in AL `16 - BX`? I think you clear AH for a good reason, right?

Comment: @AlexisWilke: `popcnt` is only available in 16/32/64-bit operand-size, not 8-bit; that's why we need a value in AH (the high half of AX) that has a known number of set bits.  In this case, zero-extending 8-bit AL into 16-bit AX.

Comment: Without popcnt, `shr` / `adc bx,0` / `test al`/`jnz` would be more efficient, using the same trick of counting ones and then subtracting outside the loop.  Or see [Hamming weight ( number of 1 in a number) mixing C with assembly](//stackoverflow.com/a/27053187) for a version that skews the loop to use the ZF (as a loop condition) and CF (adc next iteration) results from one SHR.

Answer (score 2):

Often when you write in assembly, it's fun to look at possible optimizations. Using a loop, you use the Z and C flags like so:

```
    MOV AL, <your value>
    MOV BL, 8
    CLC
Loop:
    SBB BL, 0
    SHR AL, 1
    JNZ Loop
Done:
    SBB BL, 0
    ; result is in BL
    HLT
```

A faster way on older processors is to have a 256 bytes table and do a look up. As mentioned by vitsoft, on modern processors, use the POPCNT instruction is probably the fastest (it takes one clock cycle to counts all the bits of a 64 bit register in hardware.)

Now, if you need to know the exact timing, my loop is not practical because it will vary depending on `AL`. Another way to make it go fast is to unroll the loop:

```
    MOV AL, <your value>
    MOV BL, 8
    SHR AL, 1    ; 1
    SBB BL, 0
    SHR AL, 1    ; 2
    SBB BL, 0
    SHR AL, 1    ; 3
    SBB BL, 0
    SHR AL, 1    ; 4
    SBB BL, 0
    SHR AL, 1    ; 5
    SBB BL, 0
    SHR AL, 1    ; 6
    SBB BL, 0
    SHR AL, 1    ; 7
    SBB BL, 0
    SHR AL, 1    ; 8
    SBB BL, 0
    HLT
```

This is practical because you have zero branches. Modern processors love that much (although in this case since we're dealing with just 2 registers, I don't think it's a huge advantage.)